# In pycharm debugger how do you get out of a lambda function?

Tags: python, pycharm

[image]

I would like to get out of that lambda function and on to the next breakpoint in my code. But I cannot unless I remove that breakpoint and then the debugger proceeds. Is there a button that I'm missing?